# Flutter: Cannot store Firestore data to local variable (returns null)

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have an issue when trying to store data from Firestore to a local variable.

```
class AppUser {
  String _userId;
  Map<String, dynamic> _userData;

  Future getUserDataFromDb() async {  
    _userData = await dbInterface.getFinancialsFromDB(_userId);
    // dbInterface.getFinancialsFromDB(_userId).then((Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    //   _userData = data;
    // });
    print(_userData); // flutter: null
  }
}
```

_userData always returns null.

```
class Db {
  CollectionReference financials = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('financials');

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getFinancialsFromDB(userId) async {
    financials.doc(userId).get().then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print(documentSnapshot.data()); // flutter: {'key1': 'data1', ...}
        return documentSnapshot.data();
      }
    });
    return null;
  }
}

Db dbInterface = Db();
```

Within the "getFinancialsFromDB"-Function it prints the correct Map. So the issue isn't to retrieve the data from Firestore but to store it in the _userData variable.

The getUserDataFromDb() is called in an initState.

Any ideas what I could do to fix this issue? If you need any additional infos please let me know.

Thanks a lot, I really appreciate any help.

All the best,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing code an in `async` function, don't use `then`.  Instead, use `await` to get the result of a Future.

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getFinancialsFromDB(userId) async {
    var documentSnapshot = await financials.doc(userId).get();
    if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
      return documentSnapshot.data();
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```